# Height of Element Issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, responsive

I have the following code:

```css
.embed-responsive {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.resume .resume-title {
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: #050d18;
}

.resume .resume-item {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.add {
  padding: 0;
}

@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
  .embed-responsive {
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="resume" class="resume">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="section-title">
      <h2>Resum&egrave;
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="resume-item">
      <iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QQ3lCOVEBd551AuNOA-XA4x6s1I3AaCZ/preview" width="100%" height="1070"></iframe>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

So on my end since I have the above code embedded in a website, the output looks like this:

[image]

However, when I view the website using a smaller screen, I am getting this output:

[image]

The problem is that the "template"  (which is the grey part) extends to `height: 1070` even on responsive mode. I want the grey part to end after the document with some margin like shown in the very first picture when you view it on a smaller device.

### Expected Output:

**Larger Screen**

[image]

Same picture as the very first picture I sent, so no changes here really.

**Smaller Screen:**

[image]

The Blue Line is where the grey part should end, with some margin in between the document and grey part, as there is at the top. Any suggestions on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: your problem is the height on the iframe... if the "minimum" size is basically the screen width and a standard page is basically ~1:1.4 you could make the height (in smaller screens) be 140~150% of the width

Comment: Can you show please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe something like this:

made a class for the iframe, for the media query I put 140vw

why 140vw? the ratio of an A4 paper is around 1.4 (if you know its some other format... just change the ratio...) this means the height is 1.4 the width, so you can use that instead of a number as you're doing in the default settings.

```css
.embed-responsive {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.resume .resume-title {
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: #050d18;
}

.resume .resume-item {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.add {
  padding: 0;
}

.iframe {
  height: 1070px;
}

@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
  .embed-responsive {
    height: auto;
  }
  .iframe {
    height: 140vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="resume" class="resume">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="section-title">
      <h2>Resum&egrave;
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="resume-item">
      <iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QQ3lCOVEBd551AuNOA-XA4x6s1I3AaCZ/preview" width="100%" class="iframe"></iframe>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```